# To display an error message when a record is submitted for approval using apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, approval-process, error-messages, master-detail

Please help me with this code, Writing a Trigger to display an error message on Opportunity_Support_Request__c record which has no OSR Product and if it is submitted for Approval(by clicking on Submit for Approval button)  it will display the error message(You must add at least one osr Product to your Request).

Opportunity_Support_Request__c is Master object
OSR_Product__c is Detail obj
OSR_ID__c is the master detail field created on detail object.
And the Trigger that I have written is :

```
trigger OSRapprovalTrigger on Opportunity_Support_Request__c (before insert,before update)
{        
    if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isBefore)
    {        
        for(Opportunity_Support_Request__c s : Trigger.new){                        
            if(s.Status__c == 'Not Submitted')
            {
                //Get list of osr products
                List <OSR_Product__c> SampleProductList = [Select CAT_logic_Description__c,Material_Description__c from OSR_Product__c where OSR_ID__c =: s.id ];//
                if(SampleProductList.size() == 0)
                {
                    if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
                        s.addError('You must add at least one osr Product to your Request');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please Help.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: What is the issue, did you put debug logs to check what is the size of  `SampleProductList`? And please remove `SOQL` from for loop.

Comment: Did you check that the [Customize Error Messages for Invalided Approval Process](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrecAAC) is still an idea? It's not clear if your approval process just sets the Status to 'Not Submitted'.

Comment: @NagendraSingh Hello, thanks for your reply. Anyhow I wrote this trigger as I am the beginner. Not able to save the trigger. Haven't checked the logs. Can you please share the code that fulfil my requirement ?

Comment: This is not how this forum works. We are here for providing code. If you face any issues while developing then please paste your question so that we can take a look.

Comment: @NagendraSingh , Apologies as I am new here...!!  -- Here is the error message I am facing. "
Select Quantity__c from OSR_Product__c
       ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:8
No such column 'Quantity__c' on entity 'OSR_Product__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.". Though OSR product is the child of Opportunity Support Request Obj, but I think still it is not able to detect it.

Comment: I just edited the code, it is saving but no trigger is getting fired before submitting for approval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give a sample and one of the ways to implement this:

I created an approval process, just added an action to update any field. In your case it will be your specific field.

[image: DummyApprovalprocess]

After that just wrote a trigger on Opportunity `beforeUpdate` like this. You can add your conditions.

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before update) {

    if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isBefore) {        
        for(Opportunity s : Trigger.new){                        
            s.addError('You must add at least one osr Product to your Request');
        }
    }

}
```

And when submitting for approval:

[image]

got this message:

[image]

Now you will have to fix your code for compilation errors and all, but this was just to show that this flow does work and allows us to put a validation in approval process.

Comment: a useful field to update in the Approval Process would be a checkbox called `Is_Ready_For_Approval_Submission_Validation__c` that if validation checks pass, is switched off within the before update